# "The folder 'Documents' doesn't exist" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a list of files in document folder in Swift, here's a code snippet:

```swift
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if let dir = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
  print(dir.absoluteString)              // print 1

  do {
    let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dir.absoluteString)
    print(files)                         // print 2
  } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)    // print 3
  }
}
```

Then "print 1" prints:

> file:///Users/.../.../Documents/

And "print 3" prints:

> The folder "Documents" doesn't exist.

Currently, there are quite a few files saved in that folder, at very least, my `default.realm` file is there. Why does this happen?

Comment: You don't want to use `absoluteString`. That doesn't return a properly formed file path. See Ali's answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `dir.path` in order to convert the URL to a file path:

`let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dir.path)`

Comment: This is the correct answer. you could also use `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)`, which takes a URL rather than a path string.